# Reading an Array inside an Object within Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, api, get, rxjs

Maybe someone can help me out. I have an Array within an object. I can get just the `Array(Articles)` out of the object. That is not my problem. My problem is that i am now using an `*ngFor` within Angular to read the list of Articles, but there is no `id`. The `IDs` are generated.

How can I get Angular to read from this?

[image]

I can read the array by placing in articles[0] or articles[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7E5X.png) but i need to get all articles and individually specifying is not going to work. Any help would be amazing! Thanks guys.

TS Page

```
blog: string[];
blogs: string[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
        this.getNewsData().subscribe((blog) => {
            this.blogs.push(blog);
            console.log(blog.articles);
        });
```

component.html file

```
<mat-card class="example-card" *ngFor="let blog of blogs.articles">
        <mat-card-header>
          <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
          <mat-card-title>{{ blog.title }}</mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle>{{ blog.author }}</mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
        <img mat-card-image src="{{ blog.urlToImage }}" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
        <mat-card-content>
          <p>
            {{ blog.titles }}
          </p>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions>
          <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
          <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: What's wrong with `<p *ngFor="let x of yourObject.articles">{{x.title}}</p>` ?

Comment: @bugs nothing :p

Comment: O man, if its these easy i am going to kick myself. I will recheck my code.

Comment: Still cannot figure it out. I have updated the Question with the component.ts file code. That way you can see what my object is.

Comment: @KevinSummersill what you added doesn't really provide any more context. What's the final shape of `blogs`? What does your HTML look like?

Comment: I've added my html code above. Nothing is currently reading from the array of objects. The file shape of blogs (object) is what is provided in the screenshot. Now i can of course do blog.articles which will go to the array of articles, but the ngFor will still not read the object of articles.

Comment: It will work correctly if i do blogs.articles[1] and identify a specific object in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are pushing the object you get from `getNewsData()` into an array, but that doesn't really make much sense as you only care about the object.

Change your code to this:

```
blogs;

ngOnInit() {
  this.getNewsData().subscribe((blogs) => {
    this.blogs = blogs;
});
```

Comment: Your amazing!!!!!! So every time i use the push() method, i am making it go into an array? I knew posting this to stackoverflow was worth it. Thank you for making my day great.

Comment: Yes, `array.push(thing)` adds the thing to the array. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need an id to loop through using *ngFor. It should just loop through every article in array and dispays it. If you want to give an id to each attribute in the array, generate one with a string concatenating with index.

Comment: Yea that's why this is driving me crazy. I didn't think i needed an id to read each value in an array.